# How can condensation be aided?

Tags: water, atmospheric-science, evaporation, condensation

I was wondering if certain factors of water vapor condensation can be aided? For example, being able to increase the saturation of water vapor via a certain method, or another example would be having a cool surface for it condense on. What aids are there for condensation in normal air conditions (think indoor conditions or outdoor california conditions)?

Answer (score 4):

A cooled surface is your best bet. Pressure-related phenomena are also a valid choice (basically, anything that changes the properties of the air-vapour mixture into conditions above saturation is fine), or combination of both.

A cooled surface must have high thermal conductivity to drain the excess latent heat that is emitted during condensation (metal is a good choice), and it's a good idea to drain the water as well, so that the cooling doesn't have to cool the water further -- it has high thermal capacity. Micropatterning of the surface can help to collect water into droplets quickly, and drain it away. Surface tension also helps: if the surface is water-loving (good wetting), this can lower the vapour pressure required to achieve condensation. This is amplified by micro-patterning to create many places where high-curvature meniscus forms... read up on capillary condensation ([Capillary condensation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capillary_condensation)). That's how nature does it:
[Namib Desert beetle](http://www.asknature.org/strategy/dc2127c6d0008a6c7748e4e4474e7aa1).
Also, people follow their example:
[Fog collectors harvesting water from thin air](http://blogs.ei.columbia.edu/2011/03/07/the-fog-collectors-harvesting-water-from-thin-air/)

In conclusion... with a mesh-like microstructure made of material with appropriate surface tension with water, you can condense even without cooling. With additional cooling and efficient draining of collected water, it gets even better. A metallic-fibre, surface-treated for better wetting, woven into a fine fabric, would be a fine choice.